# AWS docker set --no-cache flag

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using EB on AWS to deploy a dockerfile.

Currently I deploy to scripts:
The `dockerfile` and a `run.sh` file which starts a server.

The `dockerfile` roughly looks like this

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER xy

[...install a java server...]

ADD run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /*.sh
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

`run.sh` starts the java server.

I would like to set the `--no-cache` flag for the docker. Where can I set that?

Comment: is run.sh where you run the docker commands build and run? if you could post your Dockerfile and run.sh it might be helpful.

Comment: @booyaa No run.sh only starts the a server. I edited my question a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify `docker build`'s `--no-cache` because eb doesn't allow you to.

A workaround is to build the image locally (using `--no-cache`). Then use `docker push` to publish your image to Docker hub public registry.

Your Dockerfile could be simplified (untested) down to:

```
FROM custom_java_server_build:latest
MAINTAINER xy

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

It does sound like you're creating a large image, you might be able to mitigate this by turning the entire install sequence into a single RUN statement. Don't forget to delete all your temporary files too.

Answer (score 0):

You use --no-cache only in the docker build step.  If the run script doesn't build the image, then you need to find what is building it and tell that process to use no-cache.

Comment: How do I find out what is building it? I only deploy these two script to AWS EB.